# como se hace una barra de navegar light y desplegable con Html y Css

Tags: html, html5, iis

es que me faltaría algo en el HTML?
puse el UL, LI, y el IMG, pero no hay ningún menú
solo una selección, y imágenes con un punto, algo que no debería salir (creo)
es que soy aprendiz en HTML (versión 5), pero el css lo manejo bien

```css
body {
  background-color: aqua;
  font-family: Calibri;
  color: black;
}

img {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<title>navega</title>
</head>
<body>
<select><option OnClick="https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iis">StackOverflow</option><option OnClick="alert('stackexchange.com')">StackExchange</option></select>
<ul>
<li><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e0/Stack_Exchange_icon.svg/1200px-Stack_Exchange_icon.svg.png" OnClick="alert('stackexchange')" hide="true" /></li>
<li><img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/inficons/512/stackoverflow.png" OnClick="alert('es.stackoverflow.com')" /></li>
</ul>
</body>
<html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para hacer un menú de navegación tienes que poner la lista entre las etiquetas `<nav></nav>`. Para que te salgan en linea y sin el puntito tienes que poner en el css.

```
nav li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    }
```

El list-style:none es para quitarle el punto,el display te lo pondrá en linea mientras quepa en la pantalla.